# Subdomains for buddypress groups?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

How can I create subdomains for every group created with buddypress? Have you got any idea?

Comment: I recommend you ask this in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

create - not exactly, but using mod_rewrite you can make links like groupsubdomain.domain.eu working same way as domain.eu/sites/group  and of course make some modification to bp code or settings to display the groups links this subdomain way

Comment: But when I us this way, when I type group.domain.eu it redirects me to domain.eu/groups/group and I see in address this one

Comment: Chris what was your solution